# Java enum instances with different number of arguments

Tags: java, enums

Is there any way by which I can have an Enum in Java to accept different number of arguments so as to achieve this without using varargs.

```
public enum ValueType {
    LITERAL() {
        @Override
        String getRepresentation(String... args) {
            return MvelStringUtil.representAsLiteral(args[0]);
        }
    },

    NUMBER() {
        @Override
        String getRepresentation(String... args) {
            return args[0];
        }
    },

    //converts a string representation of a date to a java.util.Date representation, because this is what is required
    DATE() {
        @Override
        // should have two params, 1- date in string, 2- format of the passed string
        String getRepresentation(String... args) {
            // DateUtil.parse accepts dateInString and dateFormat.
            return DateUtil.parse(args[0], args[1]).toString();
        }
    };

    abstract String getRepresentation(String... args);
}
```

Here, LITERAL and NUMBER accept only one argument, that is, the target value, whereas the DATE instance accepts two. I went through several questions only to find out that this cannot be achieved using Generics since enums do not really support Generics upto that extent.

Also, from a design perspective could I just not have all the types in an Enum rather have them in a class with some workarounds, keeping in mind that this ValueType instance needed to be unmarshalled from a json and getRepresentation method would be called on the unmarshalled enum instance to get the actual representation of the target value.

Comment: put your params in a pojo e.g. "RepresentationOptions" and use this instead of plain strings

Comment: @MarcStröbel I could have done that, but there could be more types that would be added to the enum in the future. So from a design perspective it does not feel apt to pass the whole pojo of all the fields that might just not be applicable let's say :- format field from RepresentationOptions would not be applicable for LITERAL or NUMBER. just a thought.

Comment: hm, RepresentationOptions as interface and implementations for specific enum options?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible because LITERAL, NUMBER and DATE conform to the interface of the enum  ValueType. If it were possible, type safety would be violated here:

```
LITERAL()
{
    @Override
    String getRepresentation(String args) {
        return MvelStringUtil.representAsLiteral(arg);
    }
}    
...
ValueType x = ValueType.LITERAL;
x.getRepresentation("a","b"); // the compiler could not know whether this is syntactically correct
```

Comment: since enums do not seem like the way to go, is there any way i can achieve this (keeping in mind the unmarshalling), extended Generics would have definitely solved my problem here but they are not implemented at the present moment.

Comment: @VishalTyagi: There is no way to change the signature of a function that you override, it is just not possible in Java and for a good reason (see the code in my post). You can *overload* it instead by removing the Override annotation in a subclass but you need to be very careful as overloading can lead to subtle bugs in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers say, it is not possible.

Goal is to make sure you won't get wrong number of arguments for given type, so that bugs in calling code will be apparent soon, right?

I'd go with simple validation in each `getRepresentation` method implementation. Check the array length and throw exception if incorrect.

That way validity rules are kept close to the subject, which is readable. You won't know mistakes at compile time, but at least you'll know them early in runtime.

Ad design perspective - I'd keep enum. Number of types is limited, known at compile time and from quick inspection of the enum everyone will know what possibilities are there...